# How to add 2 tableviews into a single UIViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to know how to add 2 **separate** TableView's into a single View controller.

My goal is to have one tableview, a **dynamic style** (one that can read from a datasource) and then have another (this one below the dynamic) and is a **static style**. That way the static one can be used as a UI container to hold a content view. This content view will be populated with something like a graph or chart.

[Here is a mockup of what I want to achieve](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxfG2U55qf7XQWh4V2d6MXRpYk0/view?usp=sharing)

I have tried creating a UIViewController, then adding 2 separate1 TableViews to that parent UIViewController, then I make one of them dynamic and one static. The problem is I get an error saying "error: Illegal Configuration: Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances." But I cant figure out how to add both TableViews inside a parent UITableViewController.

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: why you need a uitableview with static style to show the charts? you cant just add this statc view as foother in the uitable view?

Comment: Im not sure what you are implying, could you elaborate?

Comment: if the goal of having the static style uitable view is to show the chart you dont need a uitable view for this. There are simpler and better ways to do this, you can simply add this chart as the footer view of the tableview for instance

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a UIViewController that is a delegate to

   UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

   2 uitableviews to this view controller in the storyboard

   2 IBOutlets for the UITableViews in your ViewController.h file like this:

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;

Connect the IBOutlets to these.

Add the delegate functions for the tableview in the .m file somethng like this:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if(tableView == self.tableView1){
        return whatever1;
    }

    if(tableView == self.tableView2){
        return whatever2;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances." But I cant figure out how to add both TableViews inside a parent UITableViewController.

You don't. You use a normal view controller with two child table view controllers, each with its own table. In other words, use embedded (child) view controllers:

```
main view controller -> main view
    child 1: table view controller -> table view 1, subview of main view
    child 2: table view controller -> table view 2, subview of main view
```

That's easy to configure directly in the storyboard using container views.